# How can I adjust a style attribute within a div?

Tags: javascript

Hello guys i was wondering how would I edit this using JavaScript DOM?

```
<div class="player-column" style="width: 675.556px;"></div>
```

I'd prefer a method using

```
document.querySelector(".player-column")
```

(i want to edit the width of the style btw)

Comment: `document.querySelector(".player-column").style`

Comment: In what way do you wish to edit it? Change width? Change background colour? Change value of all items that are within it? More detail please...

Comment: i wish to change the width in the element :)

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple:

```
document.querySelector(".player-column").setAttribute("style","width:900px");
```